# DjangoCMS How do I access attributes of a cms.extensions.TitleExtension in a template

Tags: django-cms

Following the official documentation under: 
http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how_to/extending_page_title.html I have created a TitleExtension which is up an and running and available in the toolbar of the cms. As example: It is a simple TitleExtension to edit meta tags according to the language of the current page.

My question is now: How do I access the attributes of the inserted values within the template? For a PageExtension several examples can be found but not for the TitleExtension.

If it would be a PageExtension with the name "FooBar" I would access it in the template via "request.current_page.foobar". Is that correct?

How would I do the same for a TitleExtension? Is there a similar comfortable way?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
{{ request.current_page.get_title_obj.foobar }}
```